# White UITabBar icons needed

Tags: iphone, ipad, icons, uitabbar

I've written a green UITabBar, but the problem I've got now is that the icons have still the same color and you can't see them very good. Is there any solution to change the color of the icons? Or add my own subview with image inside?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get white icons in PNG format here: http://glyphish.com

Simple to change the color too: drop the PNGs into Photoshop or Pixelmator and fill the layer with the desired color, and ensure the "preserve transparency" checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think ur using the "jpeg" images, try using "png" files with transparent background...
u can create a png image in any photo editing tool that supports layer options...
if u need tutorials on how to make transparent backgrounded png files go through the bellow link...
http://www.axialis.com/tutorials/tutorial-misc001.html
Hope this will help u...

~Raviraja

Comment: I'm already using transparent icons. The problem is the standart gray color the TabBarIcons have when they are unselected. The hightlighted item with shining blue is okay